# Why session id of remote process is zero?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get session Id of specified process on remote machine, but property SessionId always returns zero, but in fact, session Id specified in TaskManager on remote machine is 19.

```
var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad", "remotehost.work.com");

foreach (var item in procs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SessionId); -- session id always "0"
}
```

**Updated.** System configuratios: Windows 10 Pro x64 > RDP session > Windows server 2012 R2. CMD command "tasklist /S remotehost.work.com /FI "PID eq 33452"" returns correct session Id. Looks like this is a .Net bug.

Could be remote process session id retrieved in some other way from code without using command line?

Comment: WMI does return this information. You can query the remote `Win32_Process` class. (Too lazy to work out full code at the moment, I do such things in PowerShell. Look up any of the many WMI samples on the net.)

Comment: Is this (host name aside) your real code?  As per this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.sessionid(v=vs.100).aspx this should throw a InvalidOperationException when 'The associated process is not on this machine.'

Comment: Thx, Jeroen, I've found solution with wmi. Tolanj, no, it's not real host, I can't show real host due to our policies. This is reason why I ask question :) because according to MSDN it must throw exception. But in fact, process has been found and returned but it session ID is always zero.